# Create json from shell script output

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script version.sh in which i have code like.

```
#!/bin/sh
data = `lsb_release -a`
echo $data
```

it returned me the output like:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

so what I exactly want is want a JSON file to be created .and data should be there like

```
{'Release' : 20.04 , 'Codename' : focal}
```

I want to print data in JSON form .can anyone please help me related this ?? I am stuck here.any suggestion any help would be matter.

Comment: Perhaps an easier way would be to write a small awk script. You could pipe the output from `lsb_release` into awk, collect the values for release and codename, and in the `END` clause of awk you can generate the JSON string.

Comment: BTW, why is this tagged _bash_? It seems to be a sh-script. May I suggest to remove the bash-tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python ttp module to get this data. See the following example:

```
from ttp import ttp
import json

data_to_parse = """
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
"""

ttp_template = """
Release:    {{release}}
Codename:   {{codename}}

"""

parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
parser.parse()

# print result in JSON format
results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
#print(results)

#converting str to json. 
result = json.loads(results)

print(result)
```

See the output:

[image]

EDITED as requested (without using any package):

```
data_to_parse = """
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
"""

lines = data_to_parse.splitlines()

result = {}

for line in lines:
    if 'Release:' in line:
        line2 = line.split(':')
        result['Release'] = (line2[1].strip())

    elif 'Codename:' in line:
        line2 = line.split(':')
        result['Codename'] = (line2[1].strip())

print(result)
```

See the result:

[image]

EDITED 2. time:

New Data:

```
data_to_parse = """
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   local

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    21.04
Codename:   cocal

"""
```

The code:

```
lines = data_to_parse.splitlines()

result_list = []
result2 = {}
result_list3 = []

for line in lines:
    
    if 'Release:' in line:
        line2 = line.split(':')
        result_list.append({'Release': line2[1].strip()})
    
    elif 'Codename:' in line:
        line2 = line.split(':')
        result_list.append({'Codename': line2[1].strip()})
        result2 = {**result_list[0], **result_list[1]}
        result_list3.append(result2)
        result_list = []

print(result_list3)
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Hello Baris Ozensel, Can't we do that without the ttp package ??

Comment: Hi Neha, there should be some other ways to do that. As per my experience, ttp is the most easiest one.

Comment: I was asking because I can not install any package .so if there would be any solution without installing the package it would be great and helpful for me.

Comment: Hey thanx  Baris Ozensel . that is what i exactly want but one issue is there it is not working with multiple data. when data_to_parse will be in multi data set then it should be return like [{'Release':'20.04', 'focal', '21.04'},{'Release':'20.04', 'focal', '21.04'}]

Comment: You can create an empty list and add your data into the list. To do this, create an empty list as following `result_list = []` first. Later on, `result_list.append(result)` needs to be added in one of `if` or `elif` statement (not at the same time.) This should work.

Comment: Can you check again please?

Comment: I tried the same but when I changed the release 20.04 to 21.04 it is showing me the last one only. it is taking only last data list.

Comment: I tried  same code with 

data_to_parse = """
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    21.04
Codename:   Tocal
"""
and it is returning me like :
[{'Release': '21.04', 'Codename': 'Tocal'}, {'Release': '21.04', 'Codename': 'Tocal'}] 
that is not correct

Comment: Hello Baris Ozensel any suggestion ??

Comment: You are correct that it only takes last output. But, why hurry?? I have edited my last update, please check again. It should work if your data has similar template. If I were you, I would look for to install some packages to make it easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info) or asked but with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) generally being an optimal choice for generating and/or manipulating JSON data in/for the `shell` (which indeed *is* tagged, along with `bash`), here's how a solution using `jq` could look like:

- the `-R` option makes the input lines being interpreted as raw strings
- the `-n` option makes the `inputs` keyword stand for an iterator over all input lines
- the `[inputs | …]` array generator creates an array with one item per input line
- the `capture` filter applies a regex on an input, and turns the matches into an object
- the `from_entries` filter reduces an array of objects with key/value entries into one object
- the `{Release, Codename}` object generator creates an object by filtering to only certain fields

```sh
lsb_release -a | jq -Rn '
  [ inputs | capture("(?<key>.*):\\s+(?<value>.*)") ]
  | from_entries | {Release, Codename}
'
```

```json
{
  "Release": "20.04",
  "Codename": "focal"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UOGsVvWjMS)

If desired, adding the `-c` option would turn the output into a single line:

```sh
lsb_release -a | jq -Rnc '…'
```

```json
{"Release":"20.04","Codename":"focal"}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QqR6PhT6oa)